# Trouble with new table, cannot define Default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but on my local enviroment I can

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble transfering mysql tables from my own computer  enviroment to godaddy's hosting's mysql. As you see in the picture below, postDate is a DATETIME type that has Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, which on my computer works flawlessly, making the current date and time the default value.

However, when i try to add the table on my hosting site it gives the error you see. If i leave  "Deafult" blank it saves without a problem, but not with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

https://i.gyazo.com/0a28032d1f6c6419d44eaf21cbc94607.png

Any idea why this is?

Is there an alternative way of saving current date and time as default value on the table otherwise?

All tables use InnoDB both on my computer enviroment and at my hosting site.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Someone suggested i get mysql versions from both my machine and my hosting site.

My machine:
https://i.gyazo.com/b1cdf582ee4d980fd68fd3773ccb4f6e.png

GoDaddy:
https://i.gyazo.com/3e619a678b8d243e0f0d70b3788b2259.png

Basically, my machine has version 5.7.10, godaddy has 5.5.45

Comment: What did goDaddy say when you asked them?

Comment: I didn't. I honestly didn't know they had help for this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the versions of MySQL on both your machine and theirs.

Older versions of MySQL didn't allow `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default on `DATETIME` columns.

Newer version do.

To get your version:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Post when you know what they both are.

Comment: I added an edit to my post. It may be what you say, my machine has a more advanced version. Is there any workaround, or way to update gogdaddy's version? Thank you.

Comment: You'd need to ask GoDaddy. If you can't upgrade their's, you could downgrade your's! Sounds silly, but it might be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Yes, i could i suppose, but my problem then would be that i couldn't make the current date and time be the default for my table. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes, but you won't like it! Manually add the current date and time in your inserts.